# How to pass parameter in batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I have a vbs file which will pass 3 parameters to test.bat.

The parameter is as below

```
test.bat "zz\zz\xyz" "Messagename" "Link"
```

The batch code is

```
@ECHO OFF
Echo %1
Echo %2
Echo %3
H:
cd "%1"

SET i=1
for %%f in (Plaintext*.xml) do call :CURL "%%f"
GOTO DONE

:CURL
Echo Success
PAUSE:
curl -X POST  --insecure --data-urlencode xmlInput@Plaintext%i%.xml "%2" >>"%3" 2>&1
PAUSE:
set /A i+=1

:DONE

PAUSE:
```

Issue:
The curl command is failing as the parameter is not passing properly. But when capture the parameter in ECHO, all looks ok.. Dont know where the issue is. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only passing the filename to your :CURL function. You need to pass the other parameters as well.

```
 for %%f in (Plaintext*.xml) do call :CURL "%%f" "%~2" "%~3"
 Goto Done

 :CURL
 Echo Success
 Pause

 curl -X POST  --insecure --data-urlencode xmlInput@%~1 "%~2" >>"%~3" 2>&1
```